# How do you upload videos to AWS S3 Bucket from a browser?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am trying to upload videos to VdoCipher using their api, but [their docs](https://dev.vdocipher.com/api/docs/book/upload/browser.html) only have an example for uploading with Dropzone and PHP. I already have my own frontend that has a file dropper, so I don't want to use Dropzone. How do you make a function that has the signature

`func uploadVideoFile(file, credentials, onProgress, onError)`

where credentials look [this this](https://dev.vdocipher.com/api/docs/book/upload/credentials.html):

```
{
    "clientPayload": {
        "policy": "{{format}}",
        "key": "{{key}}",
        "x-amz-signature": "{{x-amz-signature}}",
        "x-amz-algorithm": "{{x-amz-algorithm}}",
        "x-amz-date": "{{x-amz-date}}",
        "x-amz-credential": "{{x-amz-credential}}",
        "uploadLink": "https://{s3-bucket-url}}.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "videoId": "1234567890"
}
```

Comment: We had a similar problem and finally used EvaporateJS to implement it. I can't share the solution so this is just a comment, not an answer. I'm not affiliated with EvaporateJS in any way. The implementation was not straightforward, but it worked for us.

Comment: Thanks! Can you at least say which fields in EvaporateJS `clientPayload ` and `videoId ` go in?

Comment: No, sorry. You'll need to look deeper inside it. For us it was quite a hussle back then. And we "only" needed to upload big files from the browser directly to S3 via multipart uploads.